# How to json decode linked, related items?

Tags: ios, json, swift, jsondecoder

Let's suppose this json which represents multilingual words:

```js
[{
  "id": "en_cat",
  "name": "cat",
  "def": "A cat is a domestic animal of the feline family.",
  "trans": {
    "fr": "fr_chat",
    "ru": "ru_ко́шка"
  }
}, {
  "id": "fr_chat",
  "name": "chat",
  "def": "Le chat est un animal domestique de la famille des félins.",
  "trans": {
    "en": "en_cat",
    "ru": "ru_ко́шка"
  }
}, {
  "id": "ru_ко́шка",
  "name": "ко́шка",
  "def": "..."
  "trans": {
    "en": "en_cat",
    "fr": "fr_chat"
  }
}]
```

This json has items related to each others in the "trans" (translation) nested container.

My class is straight forward

```swift
class Word: Decodable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var definition: String
    var enTranslation: Word?
    var frTranslation: Word?
    var ruTranslation: Word?

    enum JsonCodingKey: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case def
        case trans
    }

    enum JsonTransCodingKey: String, CodingKey {
        case en
        case fr
        case ru
    }

    convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: JsonCodingKey.self)
        let id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        let name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        let definition = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .def)
        self.init(id: id, name: name, definition: definition)

        // Tricky part here...
        let transContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JsonTransCodingKey.self, forKey: .trans)
        if let en = transContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .en) {
            self.enTranslation = realm.find(wordId: en) // Singleton that looks into memory for the word
        }
        // And repeat the same if logic for the other languages...
    }
}
```

What is the fastest (CPU) way to JSON Decode it?

My way of handling it "feels" wrong:

1. I decode the words using

```swift
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
let words = jsonDecoder.decode([Word].self, from: data)
```

But the words don't have any translation linked because they are not "known" during the real-time parsing.

In my example, when we parse the first word "cat", we still don't know the French nor Russian words yet.

2. So I have to decode again, once I have all the words in memory.

```swift
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
let words = jsonDecoder.decode([Word].self, from: data) // Words don't have their translations
self.saveInMemory(words)  // In my case, it is saved to Realm.
let words = jsonDecoder.decode([Word].self, from: data) 
/* Words are now linked to each others
Because during decoding, the func Word.init(from decoder) will 
look into `Realm` and find the translations. */
```

This double decoding feels like an overkill. Isn't there anyway to search into the json data directly?

Comment: Decoding does not mean to generate your final data structure. Decode objects the way they are encoded ("translations") and then link them together using different objects.

Comment: JSON represents a tree of data. You can't "link" or refrence anything using just JSON. You can do that int [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Non-hierarchical_data_models) though. But it's still won't do everything for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decode first, generate your structure later. You are trying to combine the two which does not make sense.

Your first decoding does the actual decoding, your second decoding does only the linking.

Instead of that, decode to temporary structures, build a dictionary of identifiers and use that to link them to final objects.

To be honest, there is no need to do the actual linking. It could still be completely  dynamic, using a dictionary.

One possible approach:

```
let data = """
[{
  "id": "en_cat",
  "name": "cat",
  "def": "A cat is a domestic animal of the feline family.",
  "trans": {
    "fr": "fr_chat",
    "ru": "ru_ко́шка"
  }
}, {
  "id": "fr_chat",
  "name": "chat",
  "def": "Le chat est un animal domestique de la famille des félins.",
  "trans": {
    "en": "en_cat",
    "ru": "ru_ко́шка"
  }
}, {
  "id": "ru_ко́шка",
  "name": "ко́шка",
  "def": "...",
  "trans": {
    "en": "en_cat",
    "fr": "fr_chat"
  }
}]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

enum Language: String {
    case english = "en"
    case french = "fr"
    case russian = "ru"
}

class Word: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let definition: String
    let translationsIds: [String: String]

    weak var parentDictionary: Dictionary!

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case definition = "def"
        case translationsIds = "trans"
    }

    func translation(for language: Language) -> Word? {
        return translationsIds[language.rawValue].flatMap { parentDictionary.words[$0] }
    }
}

class Dictionary: Decodable {
    let words: [String: Word]

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let words = try container.decode([Word].self)
        self.words = [String: Word](uniqueKeysWithValues: words.map { (key: $0.id, value: $0) })

        for word in words {
            word.parentDictionary = self
        }
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let dictionary = try decoder.decode(Dictionary.self, from: data)

print(dictionary.words["fr_chat"]?.translation(for: .english)?.name)
```